# Rails 3 web app + Bootstrap Twitter + Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, cordova, twitter-bootstrap

I have read a lot of articles but I am not able to get clarity. I have a whole web app built in rails3 with bootstrap twitter responsive css.

Now I want to wrap this app to android and iOS with phone gap. How can I do it

I don't want to create another client with Jquery Mobile which will interact with rails 3 backend end via Json.

- Are there any tutorials or solutions to package a rails 3 web app as android and iOS app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no tutorials or solutions for that. This is why:

> Q: Can you use PHP/ASP/JSF/Java/.NET with PhoneGap?
>   A: No. You can only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

[Source](http://phonegap.com/about/faq)

Comment: So deployed rails apps is all javascript and html5. Lets say i put a link to my website on the index.html page wrapped in phonegap. By clicking the link wouldn't it render my website inside the app itself.

Comment: I don't know how it works, sorry. I'm just quoting their FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AppCan, which can convert an existing website to a native app.